# Three divs side by side with inner div width 100%

Tags: css, html

The two outer divs needs to always stay a specific size where as the center div needs to fit the space between the outer divs. Can someone point me in the right direction

Comment: Have you got any code to show? It'll make it easier to help

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, hopefully this helps. [**`http://jsfiddle.net/QZ7ug/`**](http://jsfiddle.net/QZ7ug/)

***HTML:***

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

***CSS:***

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #BADA55;
}

[id^=container] { 
    margin: 20px 0;
    width: 1000px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div > div {
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
}

.content {
    width: 570px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.content:first-child, .content:last-child {
    width: 785px;
}

.left, .right {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    width: 215px;
}
```

**Reading Material.**

1. pagecolumn.com/liquidfixed/3_col_fix-liquid-fix.htm
2. wickham43.net/threecolumns.php

From what I can gather, the first list item is exactly what you're after:

***HTML:***

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="wrapmiddle">      
    <div class="middle">middle</div>
</div>
    <div class="left">left</div>        
<div class="right">right</div> 
</div>
```

***CSS:***

```
body {
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
}

.wrapper{
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

.header{
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #f4f4f4
}

.wrapmiddle{
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #fff
}

.middle{
   margin-right:256px;
   margin-left:256px;
   background-color: #afeeee;
   height: 200px;
}

.left{
   float: left;
   width: 256px;
   margin-left: -100%;
   background-color: #cfcfcf;
   height: 200px;
}

.right{
   float: left;
   width: 256px;
   margin-left: -256px;
   background-color: #cfcfcf;
   height: 200px;
}

.footer{
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle: [**`http://jsfiddle.net/bq485/`**](http://jsfiddle.net/bq485/)

Comment: This doesn't grow to the size of the page

Comment: His question requested somebody point him "in the right direction" and I believe I have. This is a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that uses the previous mentioned html, though jQuery will gather the widths of the 2 side divs and subtract their widths from the container, then assign it to the center div. I assumed you needed it to not be percentage widths, or else you could just assign them that. I also calculated the widths of the left and right in the chance you wanted to make one a different size. This isn't responsive either, so it calculates on page load, but if you re-size the screen it will break.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var contWidth = $('#container').width();
  var leftWidth = $('.left').width();
  var rightWidth = $('.right').width();
  var finalWidth = contWidth - leftWidth - rightWidth;

  $('.content').width(finalWidth);
});
```

[Here's a pen](http://codepen.io/jhawes/pen/Ihict)